# Сложение чисел в одной строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

В одной переменной, в одну строку, через пробел записаны числа, допустим 
 **numbers = '12 23 45 75'** (кол-во таких чисел может быть рандомным), как выполнить сложение их всех?
*P.S.* Если нужно, то у нас может быть еще одна переменная, где будет записано, сколько всего чисел находится в переменной **numbers**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = input() 
sum = sum(map(int, numbers.split(' ')))
print(sum)
```

split(' ') # разделяет все числа через пробел. 
map(int) # превращает все числа в клас int. 
sum() # сума всех чисел. 
print(sum) # выводит суму всех чисел.

Comment: извините, но чем ваш ответ отличается от предложенного ранее ответа @MaxU ?

Comment: Не используйте имена встроенных функций для переменных. Попробуйте после выполнения `sum = sum(map(int, numbers.split(' ')))` выполнить `print(sum(3,5,7))` и посмотрите что получится...

Comment: @S.Nick Этот ответ объясняет, что делает каждая строка.

Answer (score 4):

```
print(sum(map(int, numbers.split())))
#155
```